# Does "2 bumps" in a histogram suggest 2 underlying populations?

Tags: probability-distributions

I've plotted a histogram of data collected in real life, not generated data. It looks like a negative binomial binomial distribution with a 2nd bump, lower from the peak bump of the curve. Here is a screenshot:
[image: negative binomial with 2 bumps]

Question - is the second bump of any significance? Is it expected and not significant, as if produced expected to be produced by chance? Or does it indicate something, like 2 populations in my sample data?

Notes:

- Sample size - 21,700;
- Question as "In a random walk, on average, how many steps does it take to move a distance of 10 steps from the starting position?" -- but the random walk is assumed, the process that generated my data could be a non-random walk
- Uneven spacing due to most counts are even numbers
- did not do a qqplot to verify what kind of distribution, negative binomial is a guess

Comment: If you think this comes from a negative binomial, you might try generating a bunch of samples from that negative binomial and seeing if their histograms have such bumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a question like you cite, I don't see where a second bump would come from.  Another way to characterize your histogram is a dip around $59$.  It could be a problem in the way you generate the random numbers, or it could be a statistical fluctuation.  If you have a theoretical curve, you could check the chi-square.

If it is a 1 dimensional random walk, all the counts should be even, so you should make sure there are the same number of even numbers in each bin.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "For a question like you cite" -- I see, I forgot to note random walk was an assumption, I've edited the question. This was real data collected in real life; it could be a random or non-random walk, I'm not sure which.

Comment: @d l:If you are just looking at the data it is hard to decide whether it is a second bump or not.  Many embarrassing moments in science are based on this.

Comment: thank you, this tells me how to interpret my "2nd bump", which it was I was looking for.